# How to save objects of external libraries in realm?

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-java

I know I need to extend RealmObject on all the objects that I have in realm, in order to create the database, but I use google maps and so I have a list of LatLng's in a object that I need to store in Realm.
The LatLng is a google maps class, so I do not have access to the .java file, so I cannot create a copy of that object that extends RealmObject.
Has anybody found a workaround this issue, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own class (e.g. `MyLatLng`) which mimics `LatLng` structure. Next create static method inside your `MyLatLng` class which converts `MyLatLng` object to `LatLng` object and vice versa. It have to be static because only setters and getters are allowed methods in `RealmObject` classes.

Comment: Did manage somehow, but now, when I user Gson library from google, it blocks my app at the gson.toJson(obj) method